# JSON.parse: unexpected end of data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, sweetalert

estoy siguiendo un tutorial de como hacer roles de usuario en una base de datos con MySQL y PHP (soy novicio en esto). Estoy teniendo un problema al parsear el JSON y me aparecen los siguientes errores

Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character (x2)

Estoy usando el plugin de sweet alerts, el error ocurre al ejecutarse el evento 'onclick' en el boton de Eliminar Rol.

JS

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    fntEditRol();
    fntDelRol();
}, false);


function fntDelRol(){
    var btnDelRol = document.querySelectorAll(".btnDelRol");
    btnDelRol.forEach(function(btnDelRol){
        btnDelRol.addEventListener('click', function(){
            var idRol = this.getAttribute("rl");

            swal({
                title: "Eliminar rol",
                text: "¿Realmente quiere eliminar el rol?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: "Si, eliminar",
                cancelButtonText: "No, cancelar",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: true
            }, function(isConfirm){

                if(isConfirm){
                    var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    var ajaxUrl = baseUrl+"/Roles/delRol/";
                    var strData = "id="+idRol;
                    request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    request.send(strData);
                    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(request.readyState = 4 && request.status == 200){
                            var objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText); // Aquí me reconoce el error
                            if(objData.status){
                                swal("Eliminar!", objData.msg, "success");
                                tableRoles.api().ajax.reload(function(){
                                    fntEditRol();
                                    fntDelRol();
                                });
                            } else{ 
                            swal("Atencion!", objData.msg, "error");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    });
}
```

MODELO

```
public function deleteRol(int $idRol){
            $this->intIdRol = $idRol;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM persona WHERE rol_id = $this->intIdRol";
            $request = $this->select_all($sql);
            if(empty($request)){
                $sql = "UPDATE rol SET status = ? WHERE id = $this->intIdRol";
                $arrData = array(0);
                $request = $this->update($sql,$arrData);
                if($request){
                    $request = 'ok';
                } else{
                    $request = 'error';
                } 
            } else {
                $request = 'exist';
            }
            return $request;
        }
```

CONTROLADOR

```
public function delRol(){
            if($_POST){
                $intIdRol = intval($_POST['idRol']);
                $requestDelete = $this->model->deleteRol($intIdRol);
                if($requestDelete == 'ok'){
                    $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Se ha eliminado el rol');
                }else if($requestDelete == 'exist'){
                    $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'No es posible eliminar un Rol asociado a usuarios.');
                }else {
                    $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'Error al eliminar el Rol');
                } 
                echo json_encode($arrResponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            } 
            die();
        }
```

He revisado que las funciones como las variables esten bien escritas como para que sea un error de tipeo, el error esta compuesto de varias lineas que empiezan desde el evento load en el código js y siguen por la funcion fntDelRol que sirve para eliminar el rol

Comment: Puede que el problema sea el `die();` que hay en el controlador. ¿Por qué lo has puesto? Prueba a quitarlo y verifica si funciona. Si no funciona muestra por consola la respuesta en JavaScript y agrégala a la pregunta.

Comment: Lo quite y es lo mismo, lo había puesto para cortar el proceso de la función en caso de no recibir datos por POST. Recien mande el ```request.responseText``` por consola y me dice "Undefined index: idRol. . . Roles.php on line 96" como si no recibiera los datos en el controlador Roles.php ya que en esa linea tengo la variable ```$intIdRol = intval($_POST['idRol']);``` En la vista, es decir, el codigo html que no publique, tengo el input ```<input type="hidden" id="idRol" name="idRol" value="">``` El valor cambia dependiendo el id, por lo que a la hora de ejecutar la funcion este tiene valor

Comment: Ya, pero observa esto: `var strData = "id="+idRol;`, que es lo que estás mandando realmente al servidor. Ahí el  índice que tendrá el `$_POST` será `id`, no `idRol`, debes cambiarlo a esto: **`var strData = "idRol="+idRol;`**  o cambiar en el servidor la forma de recuperar el `$_POST`. Y para evitar que se genere este tipo de problemas deberías controlar en el servidor lo que recoges del POST, no ir a buscarlo asumiendo que siempre estará. Esto `if($_POST){`, debes verificar que el valor en sí está, pues aquí el POST no está vacío, pero no viene con el identificador que esperabas.

Comment: Ahí ya me funciona correctamente la función, elimine el if($_POST) y cambie el id por idRol que era el problema principal. El unico mensaje que desiste a desaparecer en la consola es el ```SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data``` pero todas las funciones y alertas funcionan perfectamente, por lo que no se si continuar con el proyecto así como esta o seguir escarvando algo que no entiendo. Gracias por ayudarme y por la paciencia, soy nuevo en la programación y muchas cosas me cuestan.

Comment: El error *`JSON.parse: unexpected end of data`*  es porque en alguna parte del flujo del programa estás sacando por pantalla algo, eso puede ser un espacio, un `die`, un `echo`, un bloque HTML, incluso un caracter invisible (BOM), que daña el JSON. Si revisas el flujo de tus programas y controlas todo correctamente ese problema debería desaparecer. O bien, ocurre porque el JSON que se genera no es válido. Eso lo puedes comprobar imprimiendo el JSON en consola y pasándolo por un validador, por ejemplo [este](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com).